# What does HTTP response 591 mean?

Tags: http

I tried searching for the HTTP 591 response but couldn't find it as a standard HTTP response. Checked the HTTP rfc but no reference for 591 response: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616

Comment: That's not a standard HTTP response code. Where did you encounter this code?

Comment: HTTP status codes starting with 5 are server errors; perhaps you should try again later?

Comment: It's not a standard HTTP status. It may be used in a proprietary website using custom codes for its own purpose (as HTTP lets you use really *any* numeric code). You should ask the developers for more info about it.

Comment: @MathiasRav, This was observed while I was trying to play my stream stored in AWS cloud. However, there was no error message logged.

Comment: @Alejandro, Thank you. That really helps. I will check with the developer on custom HTTP responses.

Comment: Null packets do not use a channel (nor a channel number) when sent and
are not acknowledged when received.